# Define Eclipse view to be opened on the left side of the workbench

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have defined an Eclipse view like this:

```xml
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            id="my.category"
            name="My category">
      </category>
      <view
            category="my.category"
            class="com.my.View"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            id="my.View"
            name="My View">
      </view>
   </extension>
```

The view is opened at the bottom of the workbench (next to the `Console` view) by default, how can I define that the view should be opened at the left side of the workbench? in the `Project Explorer` area.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to define the layout of your view in a particular perspective.

The following example is how the JUnit view is positioned next to the Package Explorer view in the Java perspective:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     <view
           relative="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer"
           visible="false"
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.ResultView"
           relationship="stack">
     </view>
```